# Customizing SXA checklist filter facet component

Tags: content-search, solr, sxa

I would like to do pivoted search using SXA Search filter facet Component. Is there a way to customize SXA Search component and have pivoted kind of search? I see that sxa delivers SearchController with two actions (Results,Facet). Does it have any action for pivot search?

Using CheckList Filter component, I can only break down the values by a single facet category but  I also want to do by any additional sub-categories.  I have two filters . Days(Category) filter and During(Sub Category) Filter . I am trying to get all morning days for a single result item. Example: location1 is open on sunday morning and monday morning. location2 is open on tuesday morning only. Now in this scenario, when I select tuesday and morning , I should get location 2 back in the Search result. Now to achieve this, I tried with one multilist field with 21 options with the combination(sun-mor,mon-mor,tue-mon etc). I created two computed field - Days to group all days  and then not sure how i should tag day to morning/afternoon/evening using the computed field. This is kind of pivoted search I am trying to achieve here.

Is there any alternative solution to have pivot search kind of functionality using SXA Component?

**Here is what I am trying to achieve:**

I have two multi select checklist filter facet on page for **Days**(sun,mon,tue etc) and **During hours**(morning, afternoon, evening). Trying to pull all morning, afternoon and evening days and allow multi selection as well.

**Here is an example:**

**Days facet Filters** : Sunday, Monday, Tueday,Wednesday, Thrusday, Friday , Saturday

**During facet Filters**: morning, afternoon, evening

Any help would be much appreacited!!

Comment: Whenever the Category is selected then the subcategories available for that category will be automatically available as Checklist filter or dropdown filter. No need for any additional configurations.
Eg. Sunday -> Morning
Monday -> Morning, Afternoon
Tuesday -> Evening Then when Sunday and Tuesday is selected, then in Sub category the below values will be available for selection.
Morning, Evening

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your use case there is no need to write any custom component. All you need to use is Search Results and Filter (Checklist) components. Filter (Checklist) can be configured so that you will be able to select multiple values. Just check **Multiple Selection** checkbox in the Control Properties dialogue:

[image]

With this option checked, you will see checkboxes next to each value displayed by Filter (Checklist). With this option you probably will like to display button which will trigger the search. To do that you need to provide **Button label**. It can be done here:

[image]

Comment: Adding more information to my question. Using CheckList Filter component, I can only break down the values by a single facet category but  I also want to do by any additional sub-categories.  I have two filters . Days(Category) filter and During(Sub Category) Filter . I am trying to get all morning days for a single result item. Example: location1 is open on sunday morning and monday morning. location2 is open on tuesday morning only. Now in this scenario, when I select tuesday and morning , I should get location 2 back in the Search result.